# Qt - problem integrating third party library (libarchive)

Tags: qt, libarchive

I'm having an error when I integer libarchive in Qt 5.14.2. I'm on windows.
This is the error:

```
undefined reference to `archive_read_new'
```

In my main.cpp file, I have:

```
    struct archive *a;
    a = archive_read_new();
```

I compile sucessfully libarchive 3.4.2 with mingw64 but I'm having trouble to integer it in Qt.

In my libarchive folder I have:

- include (containing archive.h & archive_entry.h)
- lib (containing libarchive.dll.a & libarchive.dll)

In my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "path\libarchive\include"
DEPENDPATH += "path\libarchive\include"

LIBS += -Lpath\libarchive\lib -larchive
```

But still, there is some thing I'm missing.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
I compile libarchive with Mingw64 so I have to compile my Qt application with the 64bit version of Mingw.